# Asp.net Grpc auth mutual

Tags: asp.net-core, grpc-c#

I would like to build a GRPC service on Asp.net.Core that auth a program license, at the moment my focus is this:

- **the main key should be certificate check on both systems to check if packet is from right source (client/server) and avoid man in the middle / packet edit**. I wanna avoid Https and use self signed cert to add inside ClientApp / Server. Should be enought to avoid user add fake root cert on their pc and impersonate server

I didnt found any example for this special case.

Comment: I think this documentation has all the info you need https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/grpc/authn-and-authz?view=aspnetcore-5.0#client-certificate-authentication   Mutual auth =  certificate check on both server and client side.  The server certificate is checked anytime you do regular secure connection (TLS) and the other leg is performed when you configure the client to check server's cert.

Comment: thx for answer i'll look into